# Background problems with wikia css

Tags: css, background, wikia

The wiki that I admin has had no changes to its css in quite some time, but recently it seems to be that the page size is too small or something, as the transparent green background is appearing either side of the borders.

You can see this happening on the wiki here http://rollplaydnd.wikia.com/wiki/Rollplay_Wiki

Any assistance in how to cover or remove the green background would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answer suggested by Emipro Technologies Pvt is some how fix your problem

but i think real problem was originated from code below

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1595px) and (min-width: 1084px)
.WikiaPage {
  padding: 0 20px; //remove this line or use padding in internal container
  width: 1024px;
}
```

**EDIT**: padding make your internal division to shrink and your parent container will get control on that extra area

i hope this may help you

Comment: I can't find this exact line of code in the css. Are you sure this is there?

Comment: i got this code from your site only, its in Qualaroo.scss file only

Comment: Qualaroo.scss is external style so it will not be available in source. Instead in menu item's a tag write inline style sheet. `<a style="border-left:none !important;" href="/wiki/Articles">Articles</a>`

Answer (score 0):

To remove green background:
in your Qualaroo.scss file find this class
`.WikiaPage .WikiaPageBackground`
and remove `background` property in this class

And if it is not available in your source then try following.

In menu item's a tag you can write inline style sheet.

```
<a style="border-left:none !important;" href="/wiki/Articles">Articles</a>
```

Comment: there doesn't seem to be a `.WikiaPage .WikiaPageBackground` class in my css O.o

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. "In menu item's a tag you can write inline style sheet" I don't understand this sentence sorry.